# Google Rich Snippets & Warning Messages

Tags: microformats, rich-snippets

When using the Google Rich Snippet Tesing Tool, I am getting a warning when the count=0 for the reviews->aggregate reviews snippet.  Below is an example of the HTML I am using.

Does Google not validate the review if the count is 0.  I checked when a review is added and the page validates fine. If so I am guessing I wont get the additional info shown in the SERP until someone makes a comment.

```
<div id="placeinfo" class="hreview-aggregate clearing"> 
<div id="details" class="vcard item">
    <h1 class="fn org" id="pagetitle">Showcase Cinema, Coatbridge<span class="hide">, Glasgow</span></h1> 
        <ul id="rating-review" class="clearing">
            <li class="rating-holder clearing"><div class="rating average big-rating bw-0">0</div></li> 
            <li><a href="#comment-form">Add a review</a><span class="count"><span class="value-title" title="0"></span></span></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="place-contactinfo">
        <li class="adr">
            <ul class="clearing"> 
                <li class="street-address">
                Barrbridge Leisure Centre, Coatbridge</li> 
                <li class="locality">, Glasgow</li>                    
                <li class="postal-code">, G69 7TZ</li>                
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="phone tel">0871 220 1000</li> 
        <li class="url"><a href="http://www.showcasecinemas.co.uk">    www.showcasecinemas.co.uk</a></li>
                    <li class="geo">
           <span class="latitude"><span class="value-title" title="55.8475380" ></span></span>
           <span class="longitude"><span class="value-title" title="-4.0645180"></span></span>
        </li> 
    </ul>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per spec of microformats, count should be a positive integer, and rating should be something between 1.0 and 5.0 (rating accepts other ranges, once you define them).

In other words, we (and google) do not expect an aggregate review with 0 votes, 0 reviews and no rating. When it is empty, consider not using this microformat, or consider making at least one review by yourself, this countings and rating will never be 0