# Google Rich Snippet - Error with review count

Tags: web, seo, google-rich-snippets

I have successfully implemented Google Rich Snippets on my web pages. But when I tried to use review aggregate Snippets, it gives me the below error: "**If count is specified in review aggregate, page should contain reviews. Otherwise you may want to use votes**"

I have got reviews on my page but why Google say something like this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: But he mentioned seo as a tag @JohnConde

Comment: This answer might be relevant [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3902716/2125520)

Answer (score 0):

Because you use aggregate reviews each item must include at least one of either count or votes. If your page can accept from users just votes without reviews (Reviews is not mandatory for vote in other words), you should use "votes" property, not "count"